# Facebook batch requests

Tags: vb.net, facebook, httpwebrequest, http-post

I'm attempting to build a VB.net application that will retrieve various users from facebook via their Graph API batch requests method.  My problem seems to be in performing the actual request.  When I attempt to retrieve the response, I get a 400 error back from the server saying "Bad Request".  I'm not sure if that means I am forming the body of the request poorly, or if I am attaching it wrong in the code.

Here is my request code:

```
    Dim sURL As String
    sURL = "https://graph.facebook.com"

    Dim wrGETURL As WebRequest
    wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sURL)
    wrGETURL.Method = "POST"
    wrGETURL.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy
    Dim reqStream As IO.Stream = wrGETURL.GetRequestStream()

    Dim access_token As String = "..." ' Access token removed, but it is valid

    Dim jsonReq As String = """access_token"": """ + access_token + """"
    jsonReq = jsonReq + """batch"": ["

    AddBatchRequest(jsonReq, "email1@gmail.com")
    AddBatchRequest(jsonReq, "email2@gmail.com")

    jsonReq = jsonReq + "]"

    Dim enc As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
    Dim jsonBytes As Byte() = enc.GetBytes(jsonReq)

    reqStream.Write(jsonBytes, 0, jsonBytes.Length)

    reqStream.Close()

    Dim oLabel As Label = output_label

    Dim objStream As Stream
    Try
        objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse.GetResponseStream() '<<<<Crashes here

        Dim objReader As New StreamReader(objStream)
        Dim sLine As String = ""
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        Dim ostr As String = ""

        Do While Not sLine Is Nothing
            i += 1
            sLine = objReader.ReadLine
            If Not sLine Is Nothing Then
                ostr = ostr + sLine

            End If
        Loop

        oLabel.Text = ostr
    Catch ex As Exception
        oLabel.Text = ex.Message
    End Try

Private Sub AddBatchRequest(ByRef json As String, ByVal email As String)
    If json.EndsWith("}") Then
        json = json + ","
    End If
    json = json + "{""method: ""GET"", ""relative_url"": ""search?q=" + email + "&type=user""}"
End Sub
```

I've tried a ton of variations on how to form the string body, but none of them are working, leading me to believe that I am not adding the body correctly.

Comment: Two nitpicks: first, always use a `Using` block around your streams instead of closing them manually. Secondly, `Not x Is y` can (and should!) be shortened to `x IsNot y`.

Comment: I'm really new to VB.net, most of my experience is in c/c++ so I don't know a lot of the special syntax in VB.  What does the `Using` block do vs closing the stream manually?

Comment: Closing manually just won’t happen if an exception is thrown (or you otherwise leave the function) while the stream is open. `Using` will close the stream no matter what.

Comment: There's gotta be someone out there who has some kind of idea how to do this...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to use the [Facebook SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) which supports [batch requests.](http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Batch-Requests.aspx)  You would do something like:

```
Dim fb = New FacebookClient(accessToken)
Dim results = fb.Batch(New FacebookBatchParameter("search?q=email1@example.com&type=user"), New FacebookBatchParameter("search?q=email2@example.com&type=user"))
```

I think your problem though is that the jsonReq is not a properly formatted POST body.  Paste that value here and I'm sure someone can point out specifically what is wrong.  I don't have VB.NET installed.

Comment: I was hoping someone might be able to tell me how it needs to be formatted, since their examples for making batch requests seem to be in something like python.  I really am disappointed with Facebook's documentation, their explanations and example code are so specific it is difficult to use their code in anything else.